# Why isn’t the word “plans” below “planned”?

Tags: tense

Tiger’s story isn’t over quite yet. President Donald Trump has announced on Twitter that he **plans** to award the golfer with the Presidential Medal of Freedom.

Answer (score 1):

In this context and tense, we use "plans" to show that plan is still in motion. If you were to replace the word with the past tense "planned" in your example sentence it would imply that the president *had* planned to do something but that the plan was no longer in action.

However, you *could* say:

> President Donald Trump has announced on Twitter that he *has planned* to award the golfer with the Presidential Medal of Freedom.

Saying "has planned" implies that the plan has been made in the past but is still to be executed in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Is it possible to say “he is planning” for “he plans”?

Comment: @LongPham Yes! "Donald Trump has announced on twitter that *he is planning* to award the golfer..." would essentially mean the same as "he plans" because the plans are ongoing.